# create_api_blueprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page_size'

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask-restless

I am new to python. I have used Flask-Restless (0.17.0) for a python2.7 app.

After creating an API like so:

```
manager = flask_restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db) 
manager.create_api(Roles, page_size=0, methods=['GET'])
```

It shows the following error:

```
File "server.py", line 146, in <module>  
manager.create_api(XXXX, page_size=0, methods=['GET'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restless/manager.py", line 698, in create_api
blueprint = self.create_api_blueprint(app=app, *args, **kw)
TypeError: create_api_blueprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page_size     unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

Comment: Need to see the code (around line 146 at least) to understand what's going on.

Comment: manager = flask_restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
manager.create_api(Roles, page_size=0, methods=['GET'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleBeat is right, the `page_size` attribute does exist in the [version 1.0.0 beta](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0b1/api.html#flask.ext.restless.APIManager.create_api_blueprint) but not in the stable [0.17.0 release](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.0/api.html#flask.ext.restless.APIManager.create_api_blueprint).

In v0.17.0 you can use the `results_per_page` and `max_results_per_page` attributes to change or disable pagination instead:

```
manager.create_api(Roles, results_per_page=0, methods=['GET'])
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `page_size` attribute is causing issues. I do not see such attribute in the [documentation for version 0.17](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_api_blueprint#flask.ext.restless.APIManager.create_api_blueprint), even though the attribute is present in the newer version of Flask. Check your version! :)